# Developing float layout into Flex Display layout

Tags: html, css

I have been using float layout UI for my webpage. Recently i thought to convert the same layout into flex display layout. I havent been much into flex displays and i am a complete newbie into flex layout. I am struggling to convert my webpage layout into flex display. If any one could give just a gist to some properties for the UI would be helpful. I tried some with flex display but struggled with the left banner (expressed in a HTML skeleton below) as it is completely breaking the row system.
I have posted the HTML and CSS in a fiddle. Link to which is shared.

```css
.left-block {
  padding: 24px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 41.66666667%;
  margin: 0px;
  background: #333;
  /*padding: 24px 24px 0 24px;*/
}

.right-block {
  padding: 24px 24px;
  height: 100vh;
  display: table-cell;
  width: 58.33333333%;
}

.container-fluid {
  max-width: 100%;
  /*border-left: 1px solid #ccc;
    border-right: 1px solid #ccc;*/
}
```

```html
<div class="container-fluid">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 left-block">
      <img src="~/images/logo.png" class="pull-left logo" />
      <span class="pull-left company-name">Company Name<sup>TM</sup> </span>
      <div class="clearfix"></div>

      <p>
        Sign in to your account.
      </p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-6 right-block">
      <div id="SignInBlock">
        <p class="pull-right">
          <span class="noacct">Don’t have an account?</span> <a href="#" rel="button" class="btn btn-default no-decoration">Create account</a>
        </p>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
        <div class="form-wrapper">
          <h1>Sign in</h1>
          <form action="#">
            <div class="form-group">
              <input type="email" class="form-control" id="work_email" required placeholder="Work Email">

            </div>
            <button type="submit" disabled class="btn btn-big btn-primary col-xs-12">Sign in</button>
          </form>
          <p class="forgot-password">
            <a href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#forgotEmail"><strong>Forgot email?</strong></a>
          </p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/u9wz18br/

```
<div class="left-block">
<!-- Full height banner with 40% width -->
// Some Text
</div>
<div class="right-block">
 <!-- Create Account Link floating right --> 

 // Sign In Block Here 
</div>
```

Comment: Can you be more specific on how it is breaking the "row system". Your jsfiddle is using `display: table-cell`, I don't follow how that's related to your question. Here's a great flex cheat sheet, maybe that'll help? https://yoksel.github.io/flex-cheatsheet/

Comment: Another flexbox guide: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Comment: @sallf Thanks!! This seem to be a great tutorial to understand flex concept. Btw i was trying table cell option after float layout. So thats why such blunder